# CRONOMETRO IMPRESO EN CONSOLA EN JAVA

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer un cronometro impreso en consola en java que pueda pausar, continuar, reiniciar y salir, depende lo que el usuario quiera hacer, pero la verdad no tengo idea como hacerlo, hice el cronometro, pero no se como hacer para poner lo demas, ayuda.
Este es el codigo del cronometro:

```
    package javaapplication33;
    
    import java.util.*;
    
    public class JavaApplication33 {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            try {
                Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                
                int horas;
                int minutos;
                int segundos;
                
                for (horas = 0; horas < 60; horas++) {
                    for (minutos = 0; minutos < 60; minutos++) {
                        for (segundos = 0; segundos < 60; segundos++) {
                            System.out.println(horas + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos);
                            delaySegundo();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
                System.out.println("Hubo un error.");
            }
            finally {
                System.out.println("Adios.");
            }
        }    
        private static void delaySegundo() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```